# setCursorVisible loses highlighting

Tags: android, highlighting, android-edittext

I set setCursorVisible(false) on my EditText to get rid of the blinking cursor.  Unfortunately, this also gets rid of highlighting.  Why?  How can I get rid of the cursor and not the highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just glanced at the code for `TextView`... seems it only draws the selection highlight when the private member `mCursorVisible` is true. The behaviour you're seeing is evidently by design.

To workaround it I'd try creating and setting a [`BackgroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BackgroundColorSpan.html) from the current selection.